# Particular repo in Bitbucket won't let me push: 'conq: repository access denied.'

Tags: git, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I have seen many similar questions to this on Stack Overflow, but having tried all the steps given I have run out of things to try. Hoping someone else can spot something. Here is what I have tried (this is for Mac):

1. I have created a key `id_bbu` specifically for Bitbucket
2. I have added the key `id_bbu.pub` to my Bitbucket account (I have definitely NOT added anything as a deployment key)
3. I have added this key to `ssh-agent`. When I run `ssh-add -l` I get 3 keys shown: `id_bbu`, `id_rsa`, `id_git`
4. I have added the key to my `~/.ssh/config` file,

which reads:

```
 host IBM github
 hostName gain-github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

 host github.com
 hostName github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_git

 Host bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_bbu
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

5. Output of `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` is as follows (real values changed)

OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/config line 9: Applying options for bitbucket.org
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [104.192.456.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_bbu type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_bbu-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.0.210.0xhgg76
debug1: no match: conker_1.0.210.0xhgg76
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client afd128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server afd128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:2f:f5:7u:45:6v:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:49:76:6y:40
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_bbu
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 542
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([124.183.124.2]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
logged in as myusername.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3896, received 2208 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 21554.4, received 12215.6
debug1: Exit status 0
```

6. Yet when I push to bitbucket using `git push -u origin --all`

I get:

```
conq: repository access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

7. I have tried deleting the repository and creating a new one. I have also tried deleting these keys and generating a new pair with a different name.
8. Just in case it's causing a problem,

here's my project's .git/config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/my-repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

9. I have followed all the troubleshooting [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html) and elsewhere on Stack Overflow to no avail.
10. Other repos on the same account have the same issue, and this happens whether I push or pull.

Anything else I can try or anything glaringly obvious from the above?

Thanks

Comment: So I understood correctly: this very configuration works on other repos of the same Bitbucket account on the same computer but not on this particular repo? And that one you can still pull from, clone and fetch but not push onto?

Comment: Apologies...your post made me look into the config for the other two repos - they were actually pointing at a replica repo on Github. Have repointed the URLs now, and I get the same message for those as well. It happens on pull and push. Will edit my post for clarification...

Comment: Just a thing to try out: ssh config is in xml format, so try to indent the lines after the host statements like you did in the last paragraph. Seems weird though, because a confused ssh config still should not allow you to clone in the first place but it's worth trying.
Are `IBM github` and `github.com` working properly or do they produce the same error?

Comment: Yeah they work fine. I indented the last one (and amended the capitalisation) because I read that it could make a difference. No change though. You are right though I should keep them all consistent.